# INSERT query not working

Tags: sql, database

what is the problem with this query???

```
INSERT INTO query_tbl (winner) VALUES ("yes") WHERE id = 5;
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert new row or update existsing row?

Comment: MySQL INSERT Syntax does not support the WHERE clause so your query as it stands will fail.

Comment: First of all, `"yes"` references a column with the name of `yes`, not a text value...

Comment: `UPDATE query_tbl SET winner='yes' WHERE id = 5;`

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto `"yes"` here would be inserted as a string under the column `winner`, assuming proper syntax was employed. So it is a text value.

Comment: @yanman1234 Double quotes `"` in standard SQL used to quote identifiers. Textual values are enclosed in single quotes `'`...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I was coming from MySQL which allows double quoted strings, but you are right, standard SQL would complain about that usage, or at least not perform as intended.

Comment: Yeah, MySQL has [ANSI_QUOTES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) `sql_mode`, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `INSERT` a new record then try this:

```
INSERT INTO query_tbl (winner) VALUES ("yes");
```

or `UPDATE` an exiting record (I mean change a value of a record), then:

```
UPDATE query_tbl SET winner='yes' WHERE id = 5;
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

`INSERT` does not take a `WHERE` clause, because it creates a new row<sup>*</sup> unconditionally.

If you want to update an existing row, use

```
UPDATE query_tbl SET winner='yes' WHERE id = 5
```

If you want to insert a new row, insert both `winner` and `id`:

```
INSERT INTO query_tbl(id, winner) VALUES (5, 'yes')
```

Note the use of single quotes around string literal `'yes'`.

<sup>*</sup> `SELECT` query may be executed as part of insertion sequence; in this case, a `WHERE` clause is associated with `SELECT`, not with `INSERT`.